# android switch between two canvas

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, splash-screen

I have no idea why my app isnt liking the following and would be grateful for any help.

I have a main activity that sets the following onCreate

```
setContentView(new Splash(this));
```

Splash being a surfaceview with the following in its constructor

```
this.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash));
```

Then I have a thread in Splash that waits 3seconds or 3000 miliseconds.

Then calls the second surfaceview in the main activity

```
setContentView(new GameCanvas(this));
```

Everything works fine until it calls the seoncds setContentView, the screen doesnt change, it sticks on the splash screen.

any idea why?

Here is my thread

```
new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Log.e("here", "sleeping");
                    sleep(3000);
                    //main being the main activity class
                    main.killSplash();
                    //Log.e("here", "KILL SPLASH");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

p.s i have a feeling it is because I'm calling the switch canvas method from inside a thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities are designed to be different "screens" in your application, and thus you should separate your splash screen's activity from your main game activity. Once an activity has drawn, I don't believe changing the contentView will trigger a redraw. I believe you are only supposed to call setContentView once- from the onCreate method.

Also note that each activity is automatically run in a new thread.

As an aside, you might want to follow some of the [Android Developer tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial). setContentView is primarily for establishing the layout and contents of your activity, usually defined in an XML resource, whereas you seem to be treating it as a means for switching view instances.

Comment: yea it works with everything else I've tried... just for some reason it doesnt like this time :D

Comment: i went for activity in the end, you were right worked best. thnx